# Adding a local notification once a month iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using following code

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = fireDate;
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

localNotification.alertBody = @"Have you seen your Chiropractic this Month?";
localNotification.alertAction = @"Continue";
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSMonthCalendarUnit;

localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

// Schedule it with the app
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
[localNotification release];
```

How can i set "fireDate" so that this notification runs only on lets say 5th of every month. Secondly this code is in appDelegate.h. How will i set it so that it launches only one notification each month

Comment: What is the actual question here? As long as `fireDate` is set for the 5th of the month then this should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the question is actually how do I create a date object to start from

You could start with something like this

```
NSCalendar *calender = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
calender.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];

NSDateComponents *components = [calender components:NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
components.day    = 5;
components.hour   = 12;
components.minute = 30;

NSDate *fireDate = [calender dateFromComponents:components];
```

Comment: yes, just one thing, if i set date like that and with this code in app delegate, will it only one notification each month? or the code will run it again and again and cause problem?

Comment: You would have to make sure that you only schedule the notification once. You can do this using a `BOOL` in `NSUserDefaults` or you can cancel all notifications and reschedule. The first option would be the best.

Comment: so i guess i add [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
 and then ur code and then mine code and i will get notifications each month on 5th at 12:30 :)

Comment: That's one way of doing it but if you are registering lots of notifications you may want to think about not cancelling all notifications and instead doing a check to see if you previously scheduled them to reduce the effort of deleting and recreating them